# In testing, why aren't methods being called as part of a for comprehension executing?

Tags: scala, mockito, slick, scalatest

I'm trying to unit test a method that uses the following for comprehension (all Daos are mocks):

```
val dbAction = for {
  a <- aDao.create(argumentObject.getA)
  b <- bDao.create(argumentObject.getB)
  _ <- cDao.batchCreate(argumentObject.getC)
  d <- argumentObject.getOptionalD.map(dDao.create).getOrElse(DBIOAction.successful(<case class creation here>))
  _ <- argumentObject.getOptionalE.map(eDao.batchCreate).getOrElse(DBIOAction.successful(()))
  _ <- argumentObject.getOptionalF.map(fDao.batchCreate).getOrElse(DBIOAction.successful(()))
} yield a.id
db.executeTransactionally(dbAction).map {
  case Failure(e) => throw new RuntimeException()
  case Success(v) => v
}
```

The DAOs are set up to return DBIOActions, which I can flatmap into a single action and execution on the db (executeTransactionally in this case takes the result and adds `.transactionally.asTry` to the db.run method.

I'm having an issue testing the method this is part of - I want to verify the arguments of the creation methods, but despite me throwing breakpoints literally everywhere and setting frankly ludicrous timeout times on an `eventually` block, Mockito.verify() isn't registering any interactions with any of these create methods except the very first aDao call.

It honestly looks like only the methods required for creating the end result of the for comprehension are being called, and any "side effect" methods are being ignored. I can remove my mock setup for everything except for the first aDao call and not change the output.

e: my mock setup for this section:

```
  when(aDao.create(mockA)) thenReturn DBIOAction.successful(mockA)
  val bCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass[B, B](classOf[B])
  when(bDao.create(bCaptor.capture())(any())) thenReturn DBIOAction.successful(mockB)
  val cCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass[Seq[C], Seq[C]](classOf[Seq[C]])
  when(cDao.batchCreate(cCaptor.capture())(any())) thenReturn DBIOAction.successful(Some(1))
  val fCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass[Seq[F], Seq[F]](classOf[Seq[F]])
  when(fDao.batchCreate(fCaptor.capture())(any())) thenReturn DBIOAction.successful(Some(2))
  when(dao.executeTransactionally(isA(classOf[DBIOAction[Long, NoStream, Effect.All]]))).thenReturn(Future(Success(1L)))
```

Comment: Just a wild guess: do these dao methods have _implicit_ arguments? Sometimes stubbing such methods with Mockito is tricky; You might have to pass the implicit arguments explicitly when stubbing, e.g. `when(daoMock.create(any())(/* stub implicit value --> */ any())).thenReturn(...)`

Comment: There is one implicit, but it's definitely defined and being passed around as expected

Comment: What type is `aDao.create` supposed to return?

Comment: A. Each of the DAOs returns the created object

Comment: updated with mock setup

Comment: Have you tried running in strict mode? I have the feeling your mocks are being called with slightly different arguments, the other option to verify that is to stub everything using any() and then use the expected values on the verify side